# Database not checking if username is free

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

Okay, I have another problem, the code is fixed now:

```
{ 
   //Check if user already exists 
    $un_check = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = '$un'");  
    if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0) {
echo "Username already exists";
}
else{
 // Username Free
}
```

But the database still allows usernames to be the same. 
Also, even though it says "username already exists" I still creates the account anyway?

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the username will always be `'POSTVALUE'`?

Comment: shouldn't your `mysql_num_rows($un)` be `mysql_num_rows($un_check)`??

Comment: Why don't you put a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `Username` column?

Comment: Please understand that Stackoverflow is not your personal bugtracker. Instead learn how to debug PHP code. You will do it more than once in your life.

Comment: @PedroEstrada I've tried that and I get an error.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, I know it'll be $un but I tried that as well and It still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2517092 then we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$un_check = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = 'POSTVALUE'");  
if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0) {
   echo "Username is taken";
}
else{
 // Username Free
}
```

Comment: This fixed my errors! (thanks) but it still doesn't let me know if the username exists.

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed now. (: This did the trick after I changed postvalue to $un.

Answer (score 2):

Seems typo change `$un` to `$un_check`,

```
if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0) {...
```

Always have your PHP errors turn on at-least on development environment,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: zero tolerance on typo questions and answers. you don't even point out how to enable error messages.

Comment: Glad to help you. Don't forget to check my notes though :)

Comment: the boldness and underlining is on **you**, thumbs up, hope to see you soon again.

Comment: @hakre - was that a **sarcasm** ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this :-

```
if(mysql_num_rows($un) >0)
```

to

```
if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0)
```