# Duplicate User accounts

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just recently asked a question and got my code fixed to the one below:

```
{ 
//Check if user already exists 
$un_check = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = '$un'");  
if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0) {
echo "Username already exists";
}
else{
 // Username Free
}
```

And when signing up it states that "username already exists" however, it still allows me to create the account anyway and it adds the same information to the database.

Is this a problem with my code or the database?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks!

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: This is a check, and you need to code what should happen based on the outcome of this check. We cannot write code upto your requirements here

Comment: I am aware of this and I will fix it.

Comment: @user2517092 — *Fix existing code. Throw existing code away. Rewrite code using the correct API.* is not an efficient approach to programming!

Comment: When you get [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298295/database-not-checking-if-username-is-free), please do not post exactly the same code over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to murder the script. I mean, use the `die();` function. This stops the script wherever you place it. You would want to insert it like this:

```
//Check if user already exists 
$un_check = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = '$un'");  
if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0) {
    echo "Username already exists";
    die(); // Don't continue, as we don't want to insert a username
}
else{
    // Username Free
}
```

Although this would work, if there is any other code that you still want to execute regardless of whether the username exists or not, simply place the code that inserts your users inside the `else{}` block as others have suggested.

Comment: Am I missing something or is he always checking the same user with the name $un instead of checking the content of the variable $un ?

Comment: PHP converts variables placed inside double quotes to their variable content, if that's what you're confused about.
$un = 'john';
$un_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE Username = '$un'"); will translate to **SELECT username FROM users WHERE Username = 'john'**, whereas with only single quotes, it would run the query as **SELECT username FROM users WHERE Username = '$un'**.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *forbid* entering the same values twice in a table create a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

Checking for an existent entry is one thing - prohibiting that another row with same values can be inserted is another thing.

Adding such an index works like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE `MY_UNIQUE_INDEX` ( `username` )
```

Comment: @user2517092 I edited the answer to add a link to the corresponding MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the mysql query code that adds a user to the database inside the `else` block.  This way, you will never insert into the database if the user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cases

- `Username` is not unique in your database.
- (If you don't want to change your table structure) Put the `insert` part of the code inside `else` statement.

  if(mysql_num_rows($un_check) >0) {
    echo "Username already exists";
  }
  else{
   // insert new username
  }

BTW don't use mysql_ functions. DEPRECATED

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two fold.

First, strictly from the data storage - aka database - point of view, a problem is from poorly executed database design. If the username is a field that needs to be unique, then that should be declared in the database by adding a unique index to the username column. This creates the proper database design so no a new record cannot be added if the username value already exists in the table - hence the unique index.

Sencond, your code that is checking if the username exists. Is it still creating the account after you check the database for duplicates or are you just saying that you can duplicate usernames manually in the database? If the codes is still duplicating the user, then it could be because the result is an empty set - ie no results cuz no username exists and so it won't return number of rows so change > to >=.

Comment: Well, I meant that It was still creating the account after I checked the database for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I was Passed through the same problem and my solution was this

```
<?php
//Connection Script Start
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "*******";
$mysql_database = "db_name";
$connect = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
//Connection Script Ends

$un = "userabc";
$search = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$un'";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $search);
$i = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($i==0){
//username free
}else{
echo "This username is already taken";
}
?>
```

Comment: Reckless disregard for [proper escaping practices](http://bobby-tables.com/php) will get you into trouble with this approach. Also, please **do not** use `mysql_query` in  new code. It's deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Comment: Niraj: Even with mysqli_query you need to escape as your code is vulnerable to a trivial SQL injection attack. If you want to try it, set up a database, and pass in `x' ; DROP TABLE table_name -- `, causing unescaped SQL to be run and deleting your table.

Comment: The way you're using `mysqli_query` is completely wrong. You **must** use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of string concatenation. Your original question had `mysql_query` in it, so you've made an improvement here, but `$un` should not be in your query string.